# My alternative way to count the number of ways but somehow it is wrong

Tags: permutations, combinations

There are 10 women and 8 men in total. The question is to find the number of ways to create a team of 5, containing exactly 3 women.

In the textbook's solution, it applies the Combination rule and thus, there are C(10,3) to get exactly 3 women and C(8,2) to get men.

The solution in the textbook is :

C(10,3)*C(8,2)

= 120*28

= 3360 (ways to form a team with exactly 3 women)

However, I tried to calculate an alternative way by thinking with blank spaces.

Since the team has 5 members, we have five blank spaces representing each person.

_ _ _ _ _ .

Assume that the first one is a woman and so, it has to be the one from the total of 10 women. Therefore, one from the total of 10 women is C(10,1). Now, the total number of women is reduced to 9 because we have already picked one.

Similarly, for the second woman, it has to be the one from the total of 9 women, C(9,1) and for the third woman, it has to be from the rest of 8 women, C(8,1).

For the men, the first man has to be from the total of 8, C(8,1) and the second man has to be from the rest of 7, C(7,1).

Now we try to find the total number of way,

C(10,1) * C(9,1) * C(8,1) * C(8,1) * C(7,1)

= 40320 ways (the number is ridiculously huge)

Therefore, it is obvious that my alternative way of calculation is wrong. I could copy the solution from the answer key but I want to understand why my answer is wrong and where I made a mistake.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does a "team" consist of exactly $5$ people?  That's not stated in the problem.

Comment: in any case, your alternate method takes the order of selection into account, though there is no apparent reason to do this.  That is, your method takes $\{W_1, W_2,W_3,\cdots\}$ and $\{W_3, W_2, W_1, \cdots\}$ to be two different selections.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution assumes an ordering for the choices:

- Pick a first woman
- Then a second woman
- Then a third woman
- Then a first man
- Then a second man

So, essentially, you are counting (Alice, Beth, Carly, Donald, Elmo) and (Beth, Alice, Carly, Donald, Elmo) as two separate solutions (and a few others beside -- any permutation of the women and permutation of the men is being counted separately).

Comment: OP: Observe that $40320 = 3360 \times 12 = 3360 \times 3! \times 2!$—that is, your alternate method scales the correct solution by the number of rearrangements of the women and the number of rearrangements of the men.